# ReactJS and MaterialUI: equal width for all columns of a Table

Tags: reactjs, html-table, material-ui

Using ReactJS and MaterialUI I'm trying to have the same width for all columns of a Table.
I expected to have this as a default behavior when I'm not setting any width, but it's not the case: the last column is always smaller.

I've made a small example on codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/18l6nn393q

Actually I could set the width of all columns to 33% and it would work for this specific case, but it gets complicated if the number of columns is variable.
What is the standard way to have columns of equal width using ReactJS and the Table of MaterialUI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make column have `width: 'calc(100%/3)'` so it will have 3 equal width column
I made a CustomTableCell to contain common style `width: 'calc(100%/3)'`

```
const CustomTableCell = withStyles(theme => ({
  root: { 
    width: 'calc(100%/3)'
  }
}))(TableCell);
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/6l1ypx6v3r (have issue on FireFox)

Result like this
[image]

Edit: after @fitz feedback my solution not work on FireFox. I made some change so it can better support with Firefox also

with this CustomTableCell

```
const CustomTableCell = withStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    width: "calc(100vw/3)",
    padding: "10px 24px",
    display: "table-cell"
  }
}))(TableCell);
```

Sandbox (fix issue with FireFox): https://codesandbox.io/s/xolxro983p

Comment: The sandbox is not working (it looks like it's just the fork of mine without your changes), can you edit it?

Comment: Hi, I modify sandbox and sandbox link. Please check

Comment: Ok, thank you. I tested your solution on Firefox and Edge: it works with Edge but not with Firefox. Maybe a problem with MaterialUI?

Comment: Hi @Fitz, I make modify with some style to make it can show correct on FireFox also. please check https://codesandbox.io/s/xolxro983p

Comment: @Fitz if my answer correct please mark as correct. Thanks