# can't use external css file to remove Material Ui table default style

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material Ui table for my project. I want to remove the border and change padding of the table. I found a default className for material ui table called MuiTableCell-root-40. Here is my css code for overriding the default style:

```
.MuiTableCell-root-40{
border-bottom: none !important;
padding: 0.5% 0.5% !important;
}
```

However, at the first time of reloading my page, the Material Ui table default style doesn't change. I need to refresh my page to make the external css file work. I am greatly appreciated for anybody who would like to help me. Thanks!

Comment: The Material UI website has [extensive documentation](https://material-ui.com/customization/overrides/) explaining how to customize the components. And you can always add `style={{ borderBottom: "none" }}` to your components.

Comment: Similar question can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52674100/materialui-table-equal-width-columns-using-span/52676996#52676996. To put simply, Material UI uses dynamic classes, so it's impossible to change by overwriting the class name's CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the property value in state, and change it with setState,then the react will re-render it dynamically.You should read "Dynamic variation for a one-time situation" in [Material-UI](https://material-ui.com/customization/overrides/)